# "Unspoken Tradeoff" in Convergence Rates for "Quasi-Newton vs. Gradient Descent"

Tags: optimization, convergence

**Is there an "Unspoken Tradeoff" in Convergence Rates for "Quasi-Newton Methods vs. Gradient Descent"?**

As a quick summary:

- Gradient Descent based algorithms try to find the minimum of the function they are optimizing by repeatedly using information obtained from the First Derivatives
- Quasi Newton methods (e.g. BFGS) tries to find the minimum of the function by repeatedly using/approximating information obtained from the Second Derivatives

Thus, it is almost a logical conclusion to believe that for the exact same (convex) function, Gradient Descent would on average require fewer calculations per iteration when compared to Quasi Newton Methods.

**But in the spirit of "tradeoffs" - are there any theoretical results that show Quasi-Newton Methods gain stronger convergence rates compared to Gradient Descent based algorithms ?**

For instance, since information about the second derivative gives the optimization algorithm additional knowledge about the function's local curvature - in theory, we would expect this additional knowledge would "better lead" the optimization algorithm to the minimum when compared to information only about the first derivative (especially in higher dimensional functions). **Or is this additional second derivative information gained by Quasi-Newton Methods generally negligible compared to the first derivative information, and as a result, there is no general "strength in convergence" obtained by Quasi-Newton Methods when compared to Gradient Descent?**

Thus: **Are there any theoretical results that compare the "strength of convergence" for Quasi-Newton Methods vs. Gradient Descent Based Algorithms?**

Comment: Are you interested in asymptotic convergence rates (linear vs. super linear) or some other convergence related property?

Comment: @ Brian Borchers: Thank you for your reply! Yes! Something like linear/super linear convergence rate comparison would be really good! This question has been driving me crazy lately - is there any way of showing that the additional work that is done by Quasi-Newton Methods somehow "payoffs" in terms of better convergence rates?

Comment: The standard result is that BFGS gives super linear asymptotic convergence while steepest descent gives linear asymptotic convergence.  Of course you may not care if you aren’t trying to get an accurate solution.

Comment: @ Brian Borchers : Thank you so much for your reply! Do you have any references that explicitly compare both of these? I can not thank you enough for all your help!

Comment: Just about any textbook on nonlinear programming does this.  See Nocedal and Wright for example.

Comment: Note that quasi-newton methods effectively try to approximate the hessian by using gradients computed at successive iterates rather than using the actual second derivatives.

Comment: @ Brian Borchers: Thank you so much for your comments! Today I spent the day reading more about "super linear convergence" (https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/advstatcomp/rates-of-convergence.html)